# nginx: use try_files to serve file instead of directory

Tags: nginx

My server uses nginx, and my domain serves static html web pages, i.e.

```
http://server.com/download.html
```

For various reasons, I would like that users are able to fetch `download.html` through the following URLs:

```
http://server.com/download.html  (works)
http://server.com/download       (works)
http://server.com/download/      (works not)
```

I got the first two working, but the last one always returns /404.html.

Is `try_files` able to do what I want, or do I have to use the `rewrite` directive instead?

My nginx configuration:

```
location / {
    # First attempt to serve request as file, then
    # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ /404.html;
    # auth_basic "Restricted";
    # auth_basic_user_file /var/www/upscaledb/htpasswd;
}
```

Thanks,
Christoph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a location to rewrite the URI without the trailing slash, then your existing `location /` and `try_files` directive can do the rest:

```
location ~ ./$ { 
    rewrite ^(.+)/$ $1 last; 
}
```